# How to add echo html field in woocommerce order view?

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, html, woocommerce

This is how I added HTML input fields in `functions.php`
Now when I place the order these echo fields don't show up in woocommerce orders. I want to add values and labels of these field in orders view in woocommerce.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_checkout_billing_form' , 'self_added_checkout_fieldsPk1' );

function self_added_checkout_fieldsPk1($fields)
{
echo '<div class="row" style="text-aign:center">
<div class="col m4 offset-m4" align="center">
<ul class="collapsible" data-collapsible="expandable">
<li class="">
<div class="collapsible-header"><b>Instagram Account No.1 Details</b></div>
<div class="collapsible-body" style="display: none; padding-top: 0px;   margin-top: 0px; padding-bottom: 0px; margin-bottom: 0px;">
<div class="input-field col s12">
Username: <input id="acc1user" name="acc1user" type="text" class="validate">
Password: <input id="acc1pass" name="acc1pass" type="text" class="validate">

*Note: Your Login Credentials will be safe with us do not worry.
</div>
</div>
</li>
</ul>
</div>

</div></h1>';



}
```

Comment: i want my checkout fields listed in order view.

Comment: https://docs.woothemes.com/document/tutorial-customising-checkout-fields-using-actions-and-filters/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yoy are in the wrong hook. Use following

add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_fields' , 'your_checkout_fields' );

To save those values use hook 'woocommerce_checkout_update_order_meta'

And to display in order page use - 'woocommerce_admin_order_data_after_billing_address'

you can use 'woocommerce_checkout_process' for validating your fields before saving.

Hope this helps.